# Partition by Hash - Subpartition by List

Tags: oracle, hash, partitioning

I want to create a table where I do partition by hash on one column and subpartition by list on another column. Table creation should look like below:

```
CREATE TABLE testt
(
   Id              CHAR(3),
   time                   DATE,
   month AS (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM time))
)
PARTITION BY HASH (Id) 
PARTITIONS 4 
STORE IN (ts1, ts2, ts3, ts4)

  SUBPARTITION BY LIST (month)   
    SUBPARTITION template 
    ( 
    SUBPARTITION JANUARY VALUES (01), 
    SUBPARTITION FEBRUARY VALUES (02),
    ...
    )
```

I need to maintain partition by hash for legacy reasons. I can change subpartition to Range/Hash. 
But Oracle is simply not letting me create Partition by hash + subpartition by list/range/hash. I searched a lot but didn't get even one example. Now I am wondering if it is even supported or not. Can someone please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement has invalid syntax, see http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJABBBAI.

The specification of hash partition count and tablespaces should be after the subpartition templates.

```
CREATE TABLE testt
(
    Id              CHAR(3),
    time            DATE,
    month AS (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM time))
)
PARTITION BY HASH (Id) 
SUBPARTITION BY LIST (month)   
SUBPARTITION template ( 
    SUBPARTITION JANUARY VALUES (01), 
    SUBPARTITION FEBRUARY VALUES (02),
    ...
)
PARTITIONS 4
    STORE IN (ts1, ts2, ts3, ts4)
```